# Else If statement with 2 variables

Tags: java

I have a task to write a simple *Java* program:

I have two integers a and b. If `a>10 and b<10` then it should print out "balanced" and if not then print out "unbalanced"

I know how to make this with 1 variable, but i don't have clue how to make it with 2.

Here is something I have tried:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int a = 1;
    int b = 15;

    if (a > 10 && b <= 10)
    {
        System.out.println("balanced");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("unbalanced);
    }

}
```

Comment: You're missing a close quote, and you're using `<=` instead of `<`. Other than that, it should work (even without the short-circuit operator).

Comment: @Mike Run this. http://ideone.com/DX5t0w. and read my answer carefully.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera Thank you for the help. I´am very new to programming/coding so i might get stuck to a simplest thing. But in time i will learn more and become better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code not even compile since there is syntax error. You can make your mistake correct as follows.

```
int a = 1;
int b = 15;
if (a > 10 & b <= 10) { // why <= by reading your question it should <
   System.out.println("balanced");
} else {
   System.out.println("unbalanced");
}
```

Now out put is `unbalanced`.

Now let's review your code. you have use `&`(non short circuit) and here. That's not good since always non short circuit operands evaluate both side of the expression.

So you should use `&&` (short circuit)

```
int a = 1;
int b = 15;
if (a > 10 && b <= 10) {
   System.out.println("balanced");
} else {
   System.out.println("unbalanced");
}
```

What's wrong with `non short circuit`?

Consider following logic.

```
if(name!=null&name.getFirstName()=="same"){ // Now both side evaluate 

}
```

what happen `name==null`?, `name.getFirstName()` will give you `NullPointerException`. If you use `&&` short circuit you are same from this `NPE`

```
 if(name!=null&&name.getFirstName()=="same"){ // if first case false not 
                                                              evaluate second 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `&&` instead of `&` so that it does a logical `and` not a bitwise one.

You will find it clearer to read if you put brackets around `(a > 10) && (b <= 10)` as well.

Comment: `a > 10 & b < 10` will give the same result since it is non-short circuit and (&)

Comment: (Personally I find extra brackets not so readable.)

Comment: In Java `boolean & boolean` isn't bitwise, it just doesn't short-circuit.

Comment: This is not bitwise. Answer need to be edited.